# Android Studio Menu Error "Constant expression required"

Tags: java, android

I was trying to add a menu to my Android Studio layout, and it gave me the error "Constant expression required".
Why is it happening?
This is my HomepageActivity code:

```
package com.example.myqueenbapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.example.myqueenbapp.R;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class HomepageActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button btLogout;
    TextView tvName;
    MenuItem itLogout, itAbout, itProfile;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);
        btLogout=findViewById(R.id.btLogout);
        tvName=findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        btLogout.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_homepage, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item)
    {
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.itLogout:
                Toast.makeText(HomepageActivity.this, "this page is yet to be here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.itAbout:
                Toast.makeText(HomepageActivity.this, "This page doesn't exist yet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.itProfile:
                Toast.makeText(HomepageActivity.this, "this page doesn't exist yet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if(v==btLogout)
        {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            Intent moveToStart = new Intent (HomepageActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(moveToStart);
        }
    }


}
```

This is my activity_homepage XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/queenbpink"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="12"
    tools:context=".HomepageActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivLogo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200sp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/queenb_logo_dark_on_pink" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvWelcome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="ברוכה הבאה," />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text=""
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvEmpty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btForms"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="@color/queenbpink"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/queenbgrey"
        android:text="טפסים שימושיים" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btCalendar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="@color/queenbpink"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/queenbgrey"
        android:text="יומן פעילויות" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btGallery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="@color/queenbpink"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/queenbgrey"
        android:text="גלריית תמונות" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btForum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="@color/queenbpink"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/queenbgrey"
        android:text="פורום" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btLogout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="@color/queenbpink"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/queenbgrey"
        android:text="התנתקות" />




</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my menu XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/itProfile"
        android:title="הפרופיל שלי"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:visible="true"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/itAbout"
        android:title="על העמותה"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:visible="true"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/itLogout"
        android:title="התנתקות"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:visible="true"
        />
</menu>
```

Thanks in advance!
the error is given for the three rows in the HomepageActivity where it says " case R.id.it...".

Answer (score 4):

Just use If-else or If-else-if , nothing work, just don't use switch.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Great answer, thank you! After migrating to AndroidX, those switches stopped compiling. Changed to if-else and it compiled and worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {    
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.itLogout){
        Toast.makeText(this,"You clicked Logout",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
     else if (id == R.id.itAbout) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"You clicked About",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        
     }
     return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).