# constant expression required in switch case statements in android studio

Tags: java, android

[image: constant expression required in switch case statements in android studio in bottomNavigationView]

I thought there is problem in layout files first but it is not then I tried to make switch statements into if statements but i didn't understand how to change the conditions . I am expecting that the error is solved and my application is running properly.

Comment: No, this is because you have upgrade Android Gradle plugin. Change the implementation from switch to a if ... else if  .. else if ... else code structure. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/76137919/150978

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77003602/759446 for a better answer to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading Android Version. The IDs of View are no longer final. It can change. So instead of using switch() which requires a constant value. use IF

```
if(v.getid() == R.id.menu1) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add android.nonFinalResIds=false in gradle.properities, resolved my issue.